# How come I have this simple error in Selenium?

Tags: python, user-interface, firefox, selenium

I'm on AWS micro instance. There is no GUI. I SSH'ed into it.

```
pip install selenium
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Then, I do this in the python shell:

```
>>> from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
>>> driver = WebDriver()
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

How do I make this error go away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up your SSH session to allow X11 forwarding, and run your client from an X windows session. On the server, the config /etc/ssh/sshd_config should have the line `X11Forwarding yes`. and your client side should have `ForwardX11 yes`. Then just to be sure invoke ssh with the -X option. The server side should have the program you want to run (firefox) installed.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium webdriver is a remote control for a browser, for it to use firefox the machine must have a GUI, such as GNOME, running (eg you must be able to use firefox in the normal way on that machine). If you don't have a GUI try a headless browser such as `HTMLUnitDriver` instead.